# Clock in automatically when org file is opened

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to create a hook so that
It clocks in automatically whenever org file is opened for editing 
Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You could use a file local variable setting like this in your org file:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (org-clock-in)
# End:
```

This has the benefit of only affecting the files you put it in. If you want it in every file, even new ones, you can make a hook function like this.

```
(defun my-clock-in ()
  (when (org-before-first-heading-p)
    (org-insert-heading)
    (insert " " (read-string "Heading: ")))
  (org-clock-in))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-clock-in)
```

Note this assumes there is a heading at the beginning of the file, and will add one if not. If that isn't what you want you will have to use a better logic, e.g. to search for an appropriate headline to clock into.

This might not do exactly what you want though, e.g. if you have a set of org buffers open and switch between them, it will not switch the clock between them. There are `focus-in-hook` and `focus-out-hook` that might be suitable for that.

Comment: Thanks. But isn’t it possible to insert first heading * automatically so that the hook runs without error.

Comment: (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  ‘(org-clock-in)) is this syntax ok

Comment: See the edited solution above for the syntax.

Comment: Somehow it keeps nagging you for temp saving and then there is no c:\*temp* folder.